# Designing one form to call another and not exit after child form is closed

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

I am new to NetBeans and GUI development.  I was wondering how I can design a main form that has menus that open up other forms. I know how to design a form with a button and an event listener (actionperformed), like so:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
       new SeconfFrame().setVisible(true);        // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

This will call the second frame when button is pushed, but when I exit the second frame the first one goes away too. Not cool. How can I get the first frame (the main one) to still stay up?

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 2):

> This will call the second frame when button is pushed, but when I exit the second frame the first one goes away too. Not cool. How can I get the first frame (the main one) to still stay up?

you have to change `setDefaultCloseOperations(EXIT_ON_ClOSE)` to `HIDE_ON_CLOSE`

> was wondering how I can design a main form that has menus that open up other forms.

use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) rather than bothering with [Top-Level Containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)

Comment: This does not work. which frame properties are we talking about?

Comment: look to the `frames API`, then there are answers to your question, be sure that work

Answer (score 2):

Recommendations:

- If you must have one window open another, have the dependent window be a dialog window such as a JDialog or JOptionPane. Do this, and you won't have to worry about the JVM exiting.
- And yes, a JDialog can hold as complicated a GUI as *any* JFrame.
- Having said that, you don't want to have an application with lots of windows bouncing in and out of view. If you do, re-think your design, including use of CardLayout as mKorbel recommended.

Comment: my ide does not give me an option of adding a jDialog to an existing project?

Comment: @user1456559: you don't need your IDE's permission to create and use a JDialog. Just code it. What IDE are you using by the way?

Comment: Edit: I see that you are using NetBeans, so I know for a fact that your IDE can add JDialogs into projects just fine. You just have to learn how to use the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

On the 'properties' tab of the JFrame in question goto the Tab: Set 'defaultCloseOperation' (top of the list) and change this from 'EXIT_ON_CLOSE' to 'DISPOSE' see: [DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html#DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)

Comment: what exactly do you mean by the jFrame in question? Do you mean the one i want to stay active or the second frame?

Comment: the 2nd frame the one you want to close without exiting the entire application

Comment: nope. It sitll doesnt work. When i close the second frame the first one also closes. I set the defaultCloseOperation to Dispose and the first one to exit on close but when i exit out of the second one the first one exits too

Comment: hmm it should work? see this:http://netbeans-org.1045718.n5.nabble.com/GUI-Builder-Changing-default-close-operation-td5710571.html

Comment: Are you sure it never worked? Is your main frame defaultCloseOperation: EXIT_ON_CLOSE. and is your second frames defaultCloseOperation set to DISPOSE, thus closing the second frame shouldnt close the first one, to do this use System.exit(0); because it worked on mine?

Comment: Not the right strategy here.  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)